# Hover over div sometimes doesn't change back to original color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of divs, each with a different background color. When I hover over any of them, I want it to change to gray, then back to its original color when my mouse leaves the element. Here is the code I have used to do so:

```
var originalColor;
$('.div-class-name').hover(     
    function() {
        originalColor = $(this).css('background-color');
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(125,125,125)'
        }, duration);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: originalColor
        }, duration);
    }
);
```

It animates the background change as it should. However, occasionally an element will stay faded to gray even after I mouse out, which makes me think that originalColor is being modified between when we mouse over and when I mouse out. Is there a way to set the variable in the first function and get its value in the second function without allowing it to be corrupted by hovering over another element while the first is still transitioning? (This is my assumption for why sometimes a color won't fade back to its original)

Comment: `$(this).css('background-color')` will retrieve the background color of that element when it is called. If this happens during an animation, the background color will be somewhere between COLOR_A and COLOR_B. You want to hold on to the initial value.

Comment: @RadGH: You were right. Setting my color on hover to the original color was the problem. Post this as a solution and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I added an answer, including a couple alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).css('background-color')` is accessing the color of the element the moment you hover over it. If you hover over it while it is stil doing the animation, the color will be somewhere between COLOR_A and COLOR_B.

You want to store the initial value so that you can re-use it, regardless of the current state of the animation.

*Option 2*: see @Tushar Gupta's answer about using `.stop` to stop the animation immediately. The color can instantly snap to the "destination" of the animation, using `.stop(true, true)`.

*Option 3:* Consider keeping your "styles" inside your "stylesheets" - which is more logical. You [can also use transitions](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions) to perform the animation, even without using javascript:

```
a {
    color: #F00;
    transition: color 0.5s linear;
}
a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

Note that javascript animations do still have their uses, however. but for simple color animations, CSS should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

```
$('.div-class-name').hover(function () {
    originalColor = $(this).css('background-color');
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(125,125,125)'
    }, duration);
}, function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        backgroundColor: originalColor
    }, duration);
});
```